# Seeking discussion forum for mathematics

Tags: discussion

A month ago I posted a question. It was viewed by about 50 people, received one comment (for which I am grateful), and no answer, not even an attempt at an answer. I suspect this is because the question was more postgraduate head scratcher and less high school maths homework. Can someone suggest a forum where I can post my question and get, if not an answer, at least some sort of useful feedback? Thanks in advance.

Original post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4103273/cardn-cardn

Note: This is a general question but I have no idea how to tag it as such.

Comment: That link shows a deleted post.

Comment: While I can give feedback about why your post was unlikely to get the Answer you wanted, I don't feel like researching where you might find a "discussion forum".  You are new here, so I can recommend the [site tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) and the FAQ especially about [how to ask a good Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I can see the deleted question and can notice that: Your question did not follow the standards of this website, and as such, was more likely to be closed or deleted than answered, which did happen. For example, it is expected that [math is expressed using $\mathrm\LaTeX$](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), but you expressed everything in plain text. If you fix this issue and then check links from @hardmath's comment and potentially fix other issues, then your question would have no problems receiving an answer on this site. *(Put effort into questions to get effort from answers.)*

Comment: Please understand that on this site people are volunteering their time so it's your job to present a question in such a way that someone would become interested in helping you.

Comment: I think that problem with the linked questions is that it is rather difficult to reed and that it is missing the relevant tags. Anyway, you can find suggestions of various math sites here: [Useful mathematical fora](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/95787), [What online communities apart from M.SE and MO are worth frequenting?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12828), [Are there other sites similar to MSE and MO?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16242), [Is there an MSE-like site that is more pleasant to work in?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16451), etc.

Comment: That question you linked to is hardly "post-graduate" in level, Jim.  This is a question and answer site, and it hardly seems like you were asking a question, but rather, proposing a puzzle, which is off-topic here.  Question fields are for questions.  There is not even a question mark in your question field.  Good luck finding what you're looking for.  Your welcome here, of course, when you actually have a question.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com has discusson forums, sorted by level (elementary school to college level)

Answer (score -2):

You have the following discord server, which is pretty well populated and structured: https://discord.gg/HKZZpVQV
Things tend to go fast in it though.

Comment: I recall using this server for a few months about a year ago. It was nice and has many people who really 'get' mathematics. In the sense, they understood what you are saying. However, I'd say as far as a searchable library of knowledge goes, MSE is much superior